# Unpacking a payload using Ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, byte, unpack

I have a hex payload 1703cd0650000aff79fc2802 which I would like to unpack to values. I have been given a definition:

Byte 1:

0bxx01, order: MS nibble

0byyxx, order: LS nibble

Byte 2  0bxxxxxxxx  MSB

Byte 3  0bxxxxxxxx  LSB

and so on for 12 bytes in total

And I concat byte 2+3 to get a distance in mm. Could anyone help me with an unpack that could achieve this?

I have tried to unpack using 'B8B8B8':

Byte 1, part 1: I get 0001 which I calc to be 1

Byte 1, part 2: I get 1110, which I have reversed (as LSB) which gives me 14

Byte 2: I get 00000011, which I think is 3

Byte 3: I get 11001101, which I reversed to 10110011 (as LSB), which I think is 179

So is the value 3 + 179 concat 3179 or ('00000011' + '10110011').to_i(2) which is 973

I have also tried to unpack with 'B8S>', and byte2 also gives me 973.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have so far. Please make sure to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RossJacobs The code I have tried so far is string.unpack('B8B8B8') and string.unpack('B8S>') as mentioned in my question?